# WPF MVVM C# Image updating

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, mvvm

Can please any one show me some example on web or explain Image updating in WPF MVVM C#.

My XAML code:

```
<Image Source="{Binding PicturePath}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
```

C# code

```
private string _picturepath;
public string PicturePath
{
    get { return _picturepath; }
    set
    {
        _picturepath = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("PicturePath");
    }
}

PicturePath = IconPath + @"\Logo.png";
```

And when picture change, I update `PicturePath`, but Image in program stay the same. What I need more?

Comment: Probably, you have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged to notify view about changes. What MVVM pattern do you use?

Comment: Do you have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented?

Comment: NotifyPropertyChanged you think? Yes I have it .. or you think something else?

Comment: You overwrite the `Logo.png` file and want to reload it?

Comment: You are trying to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on a string to the path.  The only way INPC will 'update' is if you change the path string.  Overwriting the file on the drive will not trigger an event.  If you want to update the image when a new image overwrites, you'll want to implement a `FileSystemWatcher`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with in my project (and I've got to say it took quite a while testing different things that seemed to almost work). You can see the commented code which was also not working 100% don't remember why)

So all my Images from app assets that are starting with "ms-appx:" I use with setting the source without loading to stream, because these never change (default images etc)

The other images that are created or changed by the user I had to reload and set the source with the result of the file read (otherwise when they were changed sometimes they were not updating)

So basically I use this converter on almost all of the places that I use images that can change (without changing their name).

define your converter:

```
<converters:ImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter" />
```

And then use like this

```
<Image Source="{Binding PictureFilename, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

(Another workaround is to name your images differently and then when you update the source path it works fine.)

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        try
        {
            var CapturedImage = new BitmapImage();
            CapturedImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
            if (((string)value).StartsWith("ms-appx:"))
            {
                CapturedImage.UriSource = new Uri((string)value, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                return CapturedImage;

            }
            var file = (StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(new Uri((string)value, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute).LocalPath).AsTask().Result);
            using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read).AsTask().Result)
            {
                CapturedImage.SetSource(fileStream);
                return CapturedImage;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Error("Exception in the image converter!", e);
            return new BitmapImage();
        }

        //BitmapImage img = null;
        //if (value is string)
        //{
        //    img = new BitmapImage();
        //    img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
        //    img.UriSource = new Uri((string)value, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        //}

        //if (value is Uri)
        //{
        //    img = new BitmapImage();
        //    img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
        //    img = new BitmapImage((Uri)value);
        //}

        //return img;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So now I made stand alone procjet only for picture binding

ImageConverter code:

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo language)
    {
        try
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri((string)value));
        }
        catch
        {
            return new BitmapImage();
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Changetopicone = new RelayCommand(param => piconevoid());
        Changetopictwo = new RelayCommand(param => pictwovoid());
        LogoSourcePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
    }

    private void piconevoid()
    {
        PicturePath = LogoSourcePath + @"\pic1.png";
    }

    private void pictwovoid()
    {
        PicturePath = LogoSourcePath + @"\pic2.png";
    }

    public string LogoSourcePath { get; set; }

    private string _picturepath;
    public string PicturePath
    {
        get { return _picturepath; }
        set
        {
            _picturepath = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("PicturePath");
        }
    }

    public ICommand Changetopicone
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ICommand Changetopictwo
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

MainWindow:

```
<StackPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding Changetopicone}" Content="Changetopicone"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding Changetopictwo}" Content="Changetopictwo"/>
        <Image Source="{Binding PicturePath, Converter={StaticResource ImgCon}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="200"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

In my program I have some problem, so I made this standalone project to be sure that works.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Please note that in my case it was not working when images are overwritten while app is running sometimes, so if you find some issues try playing with the convertor a bit more (good thing is that all this logic is now in one place so it applies everywhere you use it.

Comment: Now I found problem in my app. Because I have "PropertyChanged" on this instance and then I change Icon and go back to "PropertyChanged" class ... and doing this to infinity :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement the interface INotifyPropertyChanged, add this code, then call OnPropertyChanged() from the setter of PicturePath.

```
void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: OP is talking about overwriting the image on the drive.  In this case implementing INPC on a string to the path will not trigger what he is asking for.