# Image Doesn't Change

Tags: c#, wpf, image, inotifypropertychanged

My problem is that when i upload my image from the `OpenFileDialog` the profile picture doesn't update.

I think my problem is that I somehow need `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but I don't know how to do it with my code.

This is my code:

```
private void ProfilUploadBillede_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
        op.Title = "Vælg dit profilbillede";
        op.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
          "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
          "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";
        if (op.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            try
            {
                //Skriv data til SQL
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=fraekt;Trusted_Connection=True"))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE profil SET Billede='" + new Uri(op.FileName) + "' WHERE Email='" + Config.profil_email + "'";

                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        conn.Open();
                        int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("A handled exception just occurred: " + ex.Message, "Exception Sample", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            }
            finally
            {
                ProfilbilledeBig.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
                profilbillede.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="ProfilUploadBillede" Content="UPLOAD BILLEDE" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" Margin="187,391,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="218" BorderBrush="#FFC11E2F" Background="#FFC11E2F" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" Cursor="Hand" Click="ProfilUploadBillede_Click"/>
```

**EDIT FIXED**
I fixed it by adding

```
finally
            {
                ProfilbilledeBig.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
                profilbillede.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
            }
```

To my code :)

Comment: Without showing any properties to which you are binding in xaml, I think you just heard some terms, but do not really know what they imply. INotifyPropertyChanged is heavily documented, try to investigate a bit more and I am sure you will find a way to implement it or to at least ask a more appropriate question

Comment: I wrote a intro into MVVM a few years back. Maybe it can help you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf Change Notification is indeed one of the core elements of MVVM. It can not work without it.

Comment: Hey Icepickle, I am really lost so I don't think so :/ ...

Comment: It doesn't seem to make any sense to add a BitmapImage to the CommandText property of an SqlCommand. Its implicity called ToString() method would just prepend `file:///` to the file path. Otherwise the BitmapImage isn't used at all.

Comment: @Disko Your question doesn't have anything to do with `INotifyPropertyChanged` till now, but rather that you cannot seem to update the image in a database. From the question, I do not read any problem statement, or what should happen and what is currently happening

Comment: Clemens, I did this so the path will change in my SQL table. It might not be the exactly correct method, but it works :)

Comment: DataBase = Freakt, :D... Du skal nok vise hvor i XAML dit billede er implementeret? Desuden er der i det kode du viser intet der indikerer at du skifter billedet

Comment: Just `new Uri(op.FileName)` should do exactly the same.

Comment: @Disko, you are updating the database, where do you reload the profile(s) that got changed, where do you bind the newly uploaded image to the UI? Currently you run the upload, and as far as I can see, that was it

Comment: @Icepickle Well actually it's all I've got. I got a profile, I change the picture that already exists, and then I upload the new path to my database. I tried many things to update using the new path from database, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Clemens You're absolutely right, I just changed it. Thanks :)

Comment: And that Disko, is what is missing, what you have tried to update the profile. Can you access the `Config.Profil_Bild` (or something alike) and set the new URL to it (just like you do to retrieve the email?))

Comment: @Icepickle Yes, that's exactly what I have tried to, but that doesn't work. That's why I think it has something to do with INotifyPropertyChanged. I need to change the picture in runtime.

Comment: Right, these are the things that are missing from your question, the code that defines the model & the xaml that binds all of it together

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419701/wpf-mvvm-c-sharp-image-updating Check this topic, maybe it helps.